# Kendo MVC Grid depended dropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo grid and I need to have in inline editing two dropDownLists in two cells. The second list is depended on first one. The second can have 0 or X items. When is 0 in second, how Can I send null value to server when save item ?

Grid look like this:

```
columns.Bound(work => work.Project).ClientTemplate("#=Project.Name#").Width(350); // 1 DropDownList
columns.Bound(work => work.Spp).ClientTemplate("#=Spp.Code#").Width(100);
columns.Bound(work => work.Operation).ClientTemplate("#=Operation.Code#").Width(100);// 2 DropDownList

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Batch(false)
                            .Events(events => events.RequestEnd("OnRequestEnd_TopLinePriceGrid"))
                            .PageSize(20)
                            //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.Id);
                                model.Field(p => p.Operation).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultOperation"] as TT.ViewModel.OperationViewModel);
                                model.Field(p => p.Spp).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultSpp"] as TT.ViewModel.SppViewModel);
                                model.Field(p => p.Project).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultProject"] as TT.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel);
                            })
                            .Read(read => read.Action("WorkRead", "Home").Data("currentWeekInfo")) // Přidádo HTTP parametr s vybranným týdnem
                            .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Home").Data("currentWeekInfo"))
                            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Home").Data("currentWeekInfo"))
                            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Home").Data("currentWeekInfo"))
                           )
```

Editor template for Operation:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("Operation")
        .OptionLabel("Choose operation...")
        .CascadeFrom("Project")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .DataTextField("Code")
                          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read =>
                              {
                                  read.Action("GetCascadeOperations", "Home")
                                        .Data("filterOperations");
                              }).ServerFiltering(true); ;
                          })
                          .Enable(false)
                          .AutoBind(false)
)
```

When I click save I have always default value fot operation in request.
Thnaks for any help!

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To send null value to the server the corresponding field (Operation) in the model should be of **nullable type**. Also the DropDownList should have [OptionLabel](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-optionLabel) defined and ( in case it's primitive type) [ValuePrimitive](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-optionLabel) option set to **true**.